# Pulling out WhatsApp from backup - without restoring iPhone

Tags: backup, time-machine, restore, whatsapp.app

I have Mac (now Pro, then Air)- and iPhone backup regularly using TimeMachine.

Is there a way restoring only backed-up text from WhatsApp without restoring entire iPhone?